# How to use icon fonts properly?

Tags: xetex, unicode

I have downloaded the icon font "[Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome)" to use unicode icons to illustrate my documents.

Using XeTeX, I was able to declare a new font family like this:

```
\newfontfamily\fontawesome[
    Path=fonts/iconic/FontAwesome/
]{FontAwesome.otf}
```

This works. Now, if I want to use an icon from the font, for example the [floppy disk icon](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/floppy-o/), I do the following:

```
\fontawesome{}\normalfont
```

I would however like to have a shorter way to use this icon. I would much prefer something like `... Some text \floppy more text...` to avoid to manually have to reset the font after using the icon. I came across `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{f0c7}{\floppy}`, but it seems like this wouldn't work with XeTeX.

Any ideas on how to "shortcut" this icon in a similar way?

Comment: What's wrong with `\newcommand*\floppy{{\fontawesome{}}}` or similar?

Comment: @JosephWright Nothing :-) I guess that answers my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want a Unicode char here, you want a new command that inserts jsut the appropriate symbol.

```
\newcommand*\floppy{{\fontawesome{}}}
```

I've used an extra pair of braces to group the font change so there is no need for `\normalfont`. Note that in the usual TeX way you will need to allow for the space-skipping which occurs after the command, *e.g.* `\floppy{} more text` not `\floppy more text`.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\def\floppyA{{\FA}}
\let\floppyB\faSave
\let\\floppyB

\begin{document}
Some awesome icons:
\faSave\   %%% loads automatically  the awesome icons
\floppyA\ 
\floppyB\  
\

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was not aware that there was a package for "Font Awesome". I do prefer the answer by @JosephWright though, since it does not require additional packages and works with other fonts too.

Comment: package `fontawesome` does nothing else than defining the font family and the macros `\fa<name>`. It doesn't touch any local font setting!

Comment: I am aware of that. But the other method makes it very easy for me, to use other Icon Fonts, like the ones featured here http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/classification/dingbat, without hesitation.

Comment: `fontawesome` _itself_  defines the font family `\FA`. You can define any other icon font. It is overkill to use `\newfontfamily` for fontawesome!

Comment: Thank you. Perhaps you misunderstood, I am not using the `fontawesome` package.